# Xamarin Sqlite Multiple Databases

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin App which will use existing multiple databases for UWP, Android and IOS. These databases can be downloaded from the internet for the application use buy users or can be preinstalled. A typical example is that one can have two or more databases e.g English.db and French.db. During runtime the user can switch between the databases. Some of these databases have similar tables and I already have my models in place on PCL or Shared Library Project.

From what I have searched I have found that I can use SQLitePCL or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite nuget packages but I haven't yet found a way that can get me started to connect to connect to database files in UWP, Android And IOS projects.

I have followed this https://xamarinhelp.com/entity-framework-core-xamarin-forms/ but to use existing multiple databases I find not.

To sum up say I have 2 SQlite databases English.db and French db how would I connect and perform queries on on the databases in each platform and in runtime switch between the databases. Do I need to do this on PCL or Shared Library? How may I be helped?

Comment: Are you trying to attach the two databases so you can do joins across them? Otherwise just connect multiple SQLite connections (one for each physical database file)

Comment: thats exactly what I want to achieve but the physical files are dynamic depending on how many databases the user may download.

Comment: `...exactly what I want to achieve...` To what part of my question?

Comment: To the second part where you said "just connect multiple SQLite connections". If I may find how to do that in all 3 xamarin projects ios , windows and android.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases